# Subir archivo pdf con PHP 8 y MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

tengo el siguiente fragmento del lado del cliente donde debe adjuntar un pago en pdf junto a otros campos input text:

```
<form action="ajax/solicitudes_nuevo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" name="formulario" id="datos_solicitud" method="POST" autocomplete="off"> <!-- name="formulario" id="datos_solicitud" -->
                        <input type='hidden' class="form-control" id="id_clientes" name="id_clientes" value="<?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['id_clientes']) ?>">
                        <input type='hidden' class="form-control" id="user_name" name="user_name" value="<?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION['user_name']) ?>">
                        <input type='hidden' class="form-control" id="id_booking" name="id_booking" >

                        <div id="resultados_ajax_formulario_solicitudes_registro"></div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nombre_operador" class="col-md-1 control-label">Operador</label>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre_operador" name="nombre_operador" placeholder="Operador Logístico" required>
                                <input type='hidden' class="form-control" id="id_operador" name="id_operador" > 
                            </div>

<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6"> 
                                <label class="form-label" for="archivo">Constancia de Pago</label>
                                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="archivo" name="archivo" type="file" required>         
                                   <!-- class="form-control form-control-lg"-->
                            </div>
                        </div> 


<button type="submit" name="guardar_datos" value="guardar_datos" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos" >
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Guardar datos
                                </button>

</form>
```

El problema radica en que del lado del servidor no captura el input file, tengo lo siguiente:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
       
    if($_FILES['archivo']['error']>0){
           echo "error al cargar archivo";
       }else{
           $permitidos = array("application/pdf");
           $limite_KB = 200;
           if(in_array($_FILES['archivo']['type'],$permitidos) && $_FILES['archivo']['size']<=1024*$limite_KB){
               $ruta = 'files/'.$id_insert.'/';
               $nombre_archivo = $ruta.$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
               
               if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                   mkdir($ruta);
               }
               if(!file_exists($nombre_archivo)){
                   $resultado = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$nombre_archivo);
                   
                   if($resultado){
                       echo "Archivo guardado";
                   }else{
                       echo "No se pudo guardar";
                   }
               }
               
           }else{
             ECHO "Archivo incorrecto";
           }
       }
       } else {
    echo 'fail';
```

Necesito saber donde esta el error, ya que como se observa utilizo la dir $_FILES correctamente, algo que sospecho es que sea la ruta de mi archivo php para la subida
que se encuentra en la ruta ajax/solicitudes_nuevo.php

Comment: ¿que es $id_insert?

Comment: almacena el ultimo insert sql realizado, la idea era añadirlo o concatenarlo al archivo que se almacena, pero mi problema es que la dir $_FILES no reconoce mi archivo enviado desde el input file.

Comment: ¿y que error te da?  A ver, a mi tu código me funciona bien subiendo un PDF menor de 204800 bytes y asegurándome que la carpeta ajax tiene los permisos correctos de propietario y de escritura, y cambiando `mkdir($ruta)` por `mkdir($ruta, 0777, true);` para que sea recursivo, pues tal como tienes el código el archivo subido irá a parar a `ajax/files/id_insert/nombre_archivo.pdf` (donde id_insert seria el valor de $id_insert y nombre_archivo.pdf el nombre de archivo subido)

Comment: encontré el error, el script que envia los datos del formulario era un $(this).serialize, ahora le he pasado a new FormData(this);. Sigue sin funcionar asi que decidi omitir el envio de datos por ajax por lo que se hace directo al sv, y ya puedo leer archivos, es aceptable eso?

Comment: Eso del ajax no está en la pregunta, pensaba que lo enviabas en un formulario normal. Da igual si es por ajax o por formulario normal mientras a ti te resuelva el problema. Las cosas enviadas por ajax son para que solo se refresque una parte de la página, las cosas enviadas por formulario normal fuerzan la recarga de la página. Hazlo como más te convenga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude solucionar con el sgte fragmente jquery para la subida de input file con ajax:

```
$("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var f = $(this);

        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("id_formulario"));

        $.ajax({

            url: "procesaformulario.php",

            type: "post",

            dataType: "html",

            data: formData,

            cache: false,

            contentType: false,

     processData: false

        })

            .done(function(res){

                $("#mensaje").html("Respuesta: " + res);

            });

    });
```

La linea clave era
`var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("id_formulario"));`